# Getting an error in console despite successful sign up in Firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to sign up a new user with email and password using Firebase.

Below you can see my Vue method.

```
signup() {
      if (!this.validate()) return
      const auth = getAuth()
      createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, this.email, this.password)
        .then(() => {
          console.log("Signup successful!")
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          const errorMessage = error.message
          console.error("Signup error! ", errorMessage)
        })
    }
```

Right below my script tag I have this import:

```
import { getAuth, createUserWithEmailAndPassword } from "@/firebase.js"
```

And in my firebase.js file I have this code:

```
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app"
import { getAuth, createUserWithEmailAndPassword } from "firebase/auth"

const firebaseConfig = {
  // here I pasted the config object I got from Firebase
}

initializeApp(firebaseConfig)

export { getAuth, createUserWithEmailAndPassword }
```

When I try to sign a new user up, I get this printed out in the console:

```
POST https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:lookup?key=AIzaSyDmpWucdj9MuwM5mvjA5_TKMCFlsUXUGpg 400
Signup successful!
```

I can see that I have a new user registered in my Firebase console. Why is this error showing up then?

Comment: The flow of your program doesn't seem to pass `.catch`. Where that `POST` printing comes from?

Comment: @LucasDavidFerrero It gets printed out in the dev tools console